# Failed to resolve: 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, dependencies, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using Android Studio but when I try to add: `compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'` to my `dependencies` in my app component's gradle file, I get a banner: *Project sync succeeded. Open the 'Messages' view to see the errors found*. And in the messages pane, it shows the error message:

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

When checking [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) on github I find that the latest version does exist on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.greenrobot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22eventbus%22).

Could it be an android studio misconfiguration or something?

Here is the rest of the dependencies that works fine (without the event bus dependency):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aiesec"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is embarrassing but the issue was that the gradle file (in my project's root/base folder) did not have mavenCentral in it's `allprojects` list of repositories!

So adding the `mavenCentral()` to the `repositories` of `allprojects` as shown below fixed the gradle sync errors for me:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's worked. I was upgrading a very old project to androidX